# How can I save data to a new file every time the program loops

Tags: c#, loops, file-io, timer

I am working on a c# application that pulls data from a government weather server. I have a timer ticker implemented and it is set to run every 15 min. I currently have it saving the data to the file path using:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\path.txt", data)
```

This program will be left to run on the desktop and I want each loop to save the data to a new file. Ultimate goal is to have a folder with all the files which can be batched into the SQL database

Comment: Okay, so what problem are you having in accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just include a timestamp of some kind in the file name?  Epoch time works well, since it's just an incrementing number (so the file names will sort easily).  Something like this:

```
var epochTime = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(string.Format(@"E:\path.{0}.txt", epochTime), data);
```

Comment: that works great! how would i format it so the file name includes the date and time? MM/DD/YYY HH:MM

Comment: @kealtuve: You can format a `DateTime` object to any string representation you'd like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx  I don't recommend using *only* the format you describe, since the files won't sort properly.  But if you want to use epoch + your format then I'd recommend storing a `DateTime` variable first and using that variable to calculate both formats (that way you're not off by a millisecond or two, not that it would really make a difference but the implementation might as well be correct).